# Order of a subgroup generated by a subset of a Dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Consider the dihedral group $D_{16}$ of the octagon and $$G =
> \left\langle r_{\pi}, r_{(3\pi)/4}\right\rangle$$ where $r_\varphi$ denotes a reflection at the axis with angle $\varphi/2$. Determine $|G|$.

I am not really sure how to approach this problem smartly, i.e. I could list all products and have a look where it gets me. Has someone a hint how to do this differently?

Comment: Do you mean $\pi \over 2$?

Comment: And $(3\pi)/8$.

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean "$r_\varphi$ denotes..."

Comment: Fixed it, sorry.

Comment: The order of any reflection is $2$. Thanks, I will have a look at this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I led you astray.  You're right about the order of a reflection.  It's been a while since I did abstract algebra, and I was thinking of $r_\varphi$ incorrectly. Ignore my suggestions. I'm sorry.

Comment: Now that I've got that cleared up, I can actually help, though (assuming you're still working on this).  Since this is an octagon, one of your reflections reflects through a vertex, and one through the midpoint of an adjacent side.  Because (as you pointed out) the same reflection applied twice reverses itself the you really only need to think about products of the form $\left[r_\pi \right]\left(r_{\frac {3\pi} 4}r_\pi\right)^n\left[r_{\frac {3\pi} 4}\right]$ or essentially repeated alternations between the two reflections.

Comment: All you really need to notice is that $r_{\frac {3\pi} 4} r_\pi$ is a rotation by $\frac \pi 4$, and the answer should be clear.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that it is the whole dihedral group of order $16$. Is this correct?

Comment: It is.  This comment has been lengthened to allow me to post it.

Comment: Do you want to post the answer or shall I?

Comment: I'll do it, if you don't mind.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r_{\frac {3\pi} 4} r_\pi$ is a rotation by $\frac \pi 4$.  All rotations are powers of this, all reflections are $r_\pi$ times some rotation, thus this is the entire dihedral group $D_{16}$.